# Identificar que documento pertenece elemento Js Css

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap

Mucho gusto, me encuentro trabajando sobre una plataforma la cual tiene un elemento (select option) de bootstrap que al "inspeccionar" me muestra el elemento que quiero modificar pero no estoy muy seguro en que documento se encuentra este.

cuando miro la fuente , solo me sale el css y estilos a la derecha pero en el elemento mostrado me muestra lo que quiero pero no el lugar donde le puedo encontrar y editar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: seria bueno que pongas la fuente(codigo).. para analizar...

Comment: hola Tegito123, si disculpa realmente no estava seguro como ponerlo en codigo pero e editado la pregunta para agregar una imagen que explique mas o menos lo que quiero modificar, deseo agregarun valor en el option de 10,25,50,100 otro que diga 1000 por ejemplo pero no encuentro la fuente de donde sale este ya que lo llama por un id en la plantilla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En este caso debes agregar algo de codigo jquery y javascript: en tu hmtl de dicha pagina.

suponiendo este sea mi select al que agregare la nueva opcion:

```
<select name="datatable-buttons_length" class="form-control input-sm">
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
</select>
```

mi codigo javascript y jquery:

```
<script>
//nueva opcion para ser agregada
var option_new = $('<option value="1000">1000</option>');
//agregando option_new
$('select[name=datatable-buttons_length').append(option_new);
</script>
```

en tu caso el select no pose id, por no cual lo hice x el name, puedes hacerlo x id, name, clase css..etc..:

[Ejemplo Verificable](http://jsfiddle.net/r6ckqb2h/10/)

Espero te sirva ..suerte

Comment: curiosamente me ayudaste a solucionarotro problema que tenia al mismo tiempo muchas gracias, aproposito no se si le estoyhaciendo bien al hacer click en la palomita verde de acceptar cuando la respuesta es tan buena y soluciona algo , si esta bien asi o me falto algo?

Comment: asi esta.. bien @claus.. suerte...